# how to in ruby allocate colored cards so that I always have a set of 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have Cards.

Cards start as white, get changed to red, yellow, green. The total number of cards is always greater than six. Cards cannot become white again.

I want to allocate a set of 6 cards, no more and no less.

If there are zero red, green, yellow cards, then the set is 6 white cards.

If there are 1 or 2 red cards, then the set is 4 (or 5) white cards and 2 (or 1) red cards.

If there are zero white and red cards, but there are some yellow and/or green cards, then the set is yellow cards (up to 6) and if there are less than 6 yellow cards, the set is however many yellow cards and enough green cards.

There can be any combination of white, red, green and yellow cards always more than six.

I've been trying to figure out the code for this for a week. I keep ending up with hellacious if/then structures that are never complete.

Anyone have a suggestion of how to write the code so that a set has 6 cards, but the set is comprised of up to 2 red, yellow and green cards?

Comment: Do you have a Card (or similar) model/controller/view that you can post to your question to make it easier to see what's going on?

Comment: What do you mean, allocate? Do you mean "randomly select"? With what distribution? A trivial way is to select a pattern randomly then select cards according to the pattern; if the probability distribution is of concern, weighting the initial pattern selection is one possible answer (in particular, you might weight by number of required cards, e.g. weight of six white cards is zero with total white cards < 6, and rises with amount of white cards in total card inventory).

Comment: Should have also said:
# fill the white quota of two random white cards first,
    # then fill the red quota of 2 red cards,
    # then the yellow quota of 2 yellow cards,
    # If there are not enough cards of these three colors, fill from whatever cards remain.

Comment: This is what I have in my Scorecards index: (Scorecards are the model between User and Card)

    @cards = user.cards.merge(Scorecard.redcards).sample(2) +
              user.cards.merge(Scorecard.yellowcards).sample(2) +
              user.cards.merge(Scorecard.whitecards).sample(2)

The problem is twofold: unless there are at least 2 scorecards of each type to sample, I end up with less than 6 cards and since I am sampling, I want to get each red, yellow and green sample once (no repeats).